# thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0) error

Tags: ios, swift, exception, option-type

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
@IBAction func onbutton(sender: UIButton) {

    inputarea.text = "Success"
    getweatherdata("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")

    // UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.reddit.com/")!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getweatherdata(urlString : String){

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.setLabels(data!)
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I am trying to implement a simple weather app, i am able to compile the code but once after execution i am facing the error "thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0) error" at the function call self.setLabels(data!), I have checked the url and it is returning the data not nil.

i have the function setLabels which extract the son data and display it, i will be very glad to provide the whole code if anyone needs it.Thanks

Please find the below setLabels function, appname and templ are labels in the View

```
        func setLabels(weatherdata: NSData){
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherdata, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)

                if let name = jsonResult["name"] as? String{
                    appname.text = name
                }

                if let main = jsonResult["main"] as? String{
                    //if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
                    //templ.text = String(format: "%.1f",temp)
                    templ.text = main

                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, as i am trying to fetch the data through http/https, it opens up a vulneberality and throws this security exception, so i have added the below line in my info.plist file which handled it,

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are improperly unwrapping your JSON data. If something is mistyped, nil might be found while unwrapping. Are you using if let to parse your JSON, or a JSON parser of some kind? Would you mind posting the full setLabels() function?

Comment: i have added the code, could you please take a look, thanks